# PHP + MySQL - Display empty entries in a Google bar chart

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to implement an import/export per month graph for my website using Google Charts API with a MySQL database. Everything is ok, but I'm looking for a way to show in my chart also the months without imports or exports. Could someone please help me? [Here is a screenshot of my graph, as you can see some months missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T49NG.png)

```
    <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
         var dati = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Month', 'Imports', 'Exports'],
         <?php
         $q = "SELECT month(date) AS month, SUM(imports) AS imports, SUM(exports) AS exports FROM table WHERE year(date)=2020 GROUP BY month(date)";
         $res_q=mysqli_query($db,$q);
         //fetch data
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_q)) {
            $entry = "['".$row{'month'}."',".$row{'imports'}.",".$row{'exports'}."],";
            echo $entry;
         }
         ?>
         ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Imports and Exports',
            subtitle: 'Bar chart',
          }
        };
        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
        chart.draw(dati, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? When there is no data, there is no bar on your screenshot... should be correct, or not?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'd like to show an empty bar when there is no data.

Comment: Why not tweak the picture to show us how you would like it to look?

Comment: But it seems to me to be a case of initialising a little 'for' loop right around where your 'while' clause is

Comment: I'd like to see something like this [link](https://imgur.com/a/4x72AT5).
I tried with a for loop, but I failed

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
<?php

$array = array(1,2,3,5,7,11);

for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
  if(in_array($i,$array)){echo $i.' yes<br>';} else {echo $i.' no<br>';}
    }


?>
```

Comment: I tried this inside the while: for($i=1;$i<13;$i++){
               if($i==$row{'month'}){
                 $entry = "['".$row{'month'}."',".$row{'import'}.",".$row{'export'}."],";
                 echo $entry;
               }
               else {
                 $entry = "['$i',0,0],";
                 echo $entry;
               }
But this is the [result](https://imgur.com/a/hIiwwZK)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an additional array that holds your data and that contains all the months:

```
<?php
// prepare array with default 'empty' data
$entries = []
for ($m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++) {
    $entries[$m] = '[]';
}
```

And then add the existing data to this array by overwriting the default values:

```
// fetch data
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_q)) {
    $entries[$row['month']] = "['".$row{'month'}."',".$row{'imports'}.",".$row{'exports'}."]";
}

// output
echo implode(',', $entries);
```